# How to set different footers for home page and admin page using react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using reactjs to complete my project. I have created a footer for home page .now i want to use that footer for admin page after logging. I just have changed their rout from  Foe e.g /FAQ to /user/FAQ using same component .But when i click links in admin footer it  goes on that link but on that page it is also have footer which is set for home page. I want that page which is having my admin footer .

Comment: Show us a simplified example of your code

Comment: You may create 2 separate footer component and render them in you page footer based on your condition

Answer (score 0):

Admin-dashboard
import Footer from '../../components/secondary-footer.js';

Seconadry-footer

Terms of Use

normal-footer

Terms of Use

route for seconadry footer
 
route for normal footer